# what is the difference between log.cleaner.delete.retention.ms and log.retention.ms in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

In the document

```
log.cleaner.delete.retention.ms: How long are delete records retained?

log.retention.ms: The number of milliseconds to keep a log file before deleting it
```

I cannot tell the difference between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`log.cleaner.delete.retention.ms` appplies to the topics with **cleanup policy "compact"**. It is the amount of time to retain delete tombstone markers for log compacted topics.
A message will a key and null payload is called Tombstone message. Those messages are removed during log compaction.

`log.retention.ms` applies to the topics with **cleanup policy "delete"**. It controls the time to keep the log file before deleting it.

You can find more details here : http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#configuration